# Mark only Event's start date on calendar?

Tags: 7, datetime

I am using calendar module, I created a view of calendar type that showing the event start date and end date. I just only want to mark the start date of event (Like change the background color.). How to do that?

Currently showing like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took different `Start date` and `End date` field.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the end date the same as the start date

Comment: I know it will work but if end date can be differ so how to setup it in view? I can do it with an another end date field. But I preferred it to work in view.